# Error with the array returning through function

Tags: c, string, user-defined-functions

I need to read a word from main function and convert the characters in UCASE if the first character is LCASE and vice versa using the user defined function.I tried ways for returning the array from function but still I am lacking some core ideas. Please debug this program and explain the way it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int* low (char str)
{
    int i;
   for (i=1; i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]<91)
        {
            str[i]=str[i]+32;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    return &str;
}
int* high (char str[50])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>91)
        {
            str[i]=str[i]-32;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    return &str;
}
void main()
{
    char str[50];
    char* strl;
    printf("Enter any string....\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    if (str[0]<91)
    {
        *strl=low(str);
    }
    else
    {
        *strl=high(str);
    }
    printf("Converted string is %s.",*strl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a problem here:
So if you are saying this code is perfect and you want us to debug it and explain how (on earth) this works, then here you go.

In function `int* low (char str)`, you have `if(str[i]<91)`. Thats a problem right there. `str` is a `char` received as an argument, and hence `str[i]` is a straight compile-time error.

Another one to deal with is the return statement.
You have a statement:

```
return &str;
```

which would return the address of `str`, which by the way is a `char`, whereas function `low` is supposed to return a pointer to an `int`.

The same is applicable to `high` function as well.

Suggestion: Leave aside this bad code and get a beginner level C programming book first. Read it and the try some codes out of it.

---

A few inputs for improvement: (Which you may not comprehend)

change

```
void main()
```

to

```
int main(void)
```

Why? Refer this legendary post: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Secondly, int both functions you are using `strlen()` in loop which will always return a fixed value. So, instead of

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(str);i++)
```

I'd suggest,

```
size_t strlength = strlen(str);
for (i=0; i < strlength; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code and method as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* caseConverter (char *str)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]>=65 && str[i]<=90)
        {
            str[i]=str[i]+32; //To lower case
        }
        else if((str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122))
        {
            str[i]=str[i]-32; //To upper case
        }
        else
        printf("%c is not an alphabet \n",str[i]);
    }
    return str;
}
void main()
{
    char inputStr[50]= "Stubborn";
    char* opStr= caseConverter(inputStr);
    printf("Converted string is %s",opStr);
}
```